# How to keep the original document when projecting in mongodb?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, aggregation-framework, database

I want to use mongodb's AggregationFramework with the C# driver to create a long aggregation pipeline.

Unfortunately I get a strange error while trying to maintain the original record in my pipeline.

Using the code below, I get:

```
var entry = battleLogs.Aggregate()
            .Project(x => new
            {
                Record = x, // Code works when this line is commented out
                CSum = x.Player1.Score + x.Player2.Score,
                ...
            })
            .First();
```

I get this error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: "$project or $group does not support {document}."
```

I compute a number of additional properties along the pipeline, and I need to keep the original record/document I'm working with.

I tried to copy over every member of the document into a new member of the anonymous object (using the same name).

That works, but the document (a BattleLog) has a lot of fields, so copying every single field manually into a new anonymous object would be a lot of work and unnecessarily pollute the scope when only a few properties are needed at a time.

Why is that error happening and what can I do to prevent it?

edit:
The equivalent I'm looking for is the `$addFields` function in the native mongodb-script.
What I would have to do would be to add all the fields into the anonymous object that I want to keep, but with many fields in the root document that's to much, so I want to keep the original document along the aggregation pipeline.

Maybe there's some trick using `dynamic` types?

Comment: I am not familiar with C# driver, but in MongoShell you can use `$$ROOT` as a key. E.g.:

`{ $project : { record : "$$ROOT" } }`

I hope it helps

Comment: anything  you can do  in  mongoshell you can convert it using c#  driver and construct query  document step by step

Comment: @AlexDenisov I think it's a bug in the driver then, it should translate that into what you said...

BRAHIMKamel: I'm aware of that, but unfortunately constructing queries with the BsonDocument syntax is convoluted and not really intuitive. I'd like to stick to the fluent api if possible because it works really well otherwise.

Comment: @Felheart just give us the equivalent Mongo query

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel That would be `{ $project : { Player1:1, Player2:1, TimeStamp:1, .... <some computed properties> } }`. This could be achived by including all fields of the source document in the new anonymous type, but it would be a lot of work for documents with many fields at the root level. I saw there's also the `$addFields` operator which does what I want in the mongo query syntax, but the c# driver does not seem to use it.